# Python Insert Image to Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im creating a simple chat box in Python and I want to insert an image(emoticons) to a TKinter text widget. I have tried it using this code:

```
img = Image.open("icon.jpg")
self.bigText.insert(END, img)  # bigText is the text widget
```

Output of the code above is

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile instance at 0x01AB5A30>
```

instead of the image.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think you need to use [`image_create`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.image_create-method).  Something like:

```
self.bigText.image_create(END, image=img)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: If it doesn't, we'll have to wait for @BryanOakley to come along -- He's the resident Tk/Tkinter expert around these parts.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it using:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

self.myEmoticons.append(self.smiley)
self.bigText.image_create(END,image = self.myEmoticons[self.myEmoticonsCtr])
self.myEmoticonsCtr=self.myEmoticonsCtr + 1
```

Comment: Where's the rest of it? Could you provide a complete, minimal example of the working implementation?