# Tkinter : How to insert an image to a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a notepad-like project and I need to insert an image to the Tkinter Text widget (Just like how MS Word does) and I didn't found anything helping me with this.

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import *


text = Text(root)
root.pack()
#Insert Image

yourImage=filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select your image",filetypes = [("Image Files","*.png"),("Image Files","*.jpg")])
imgFile=Image.open(yourImage)
imgToInsert=ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgFile)

text.image_create("current",image=imgToInsert)
```

But when I run it, it just shows a white image with nothing on it.

What's WRONG with my code ? Can somebody please explain this to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Insert Image to Tkinter Text Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419308/python-insert-image-to-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I did, and it is still not working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `image_create` or `window_create` example of both in use

This example doesn't use PIL, only PhotoImage which can only take a gif image file.

Example Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def add_image():
    text.image_create(tk.END, image = img) # Example 1
    text.window_create(tk.END, window = tk.Label(text, image = img)) # Example 2

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)

tk.Button(root, text = "Insert", command = add_image).pack()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file = "myImage.gif")

root.mainloop()
```

---

Also, in your code I don't see how you are using the image selected. `yourImage` is not used anywhere

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question using yourImage now. But how can you delete that image afterwards ?

Comment: Um ... backspace it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root=Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
#Insert Image

yourImage=filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select your image",filetypes = [("Image Files","*.png"),("Image Files","*.jpg")])
#imgFile=Image.open(yourImage)
imgToInsert=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=yourImage)

text.image_create("current",image=imgToInsert)
root.mainloop()
```